# Why am I getting no updates or anything when I do an update/upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and have been for some time. There is usually at least one or two things that update/upgrade in a week but for a while now I have been running sudo aptitude update/upgrade in Terminal (and sometimes using the Updater) but have got absolutely nothing. This has been a long while and I am worried that I am not getting things or something has gone wrong. What do I do?

Comment: It is almost one week with no updates in my system(s) too. I guess it is related to Christmas and end of year.

Comment: You're yet another one. Let me guess, it has been since the 17th? I'd start by changing your mirrors. There's a bunch with unknown status here:https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors, though the number is finally going down and it's only 48. It was 92 last night.